# Python Pandas: Count of datetime items between dateindex and next dateindex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Python 3.3.3
Pandas 0.12.0

I'm relatively new to Pandas and Python in general. I have a DataFrame (work hours over time) that uses a datetime index. I also have a list of dates that I took vacation (also in datetime format).

I have resampled the DataFrame into 28 day blocks, and I'm hoping to add a column that has the number of vacation days taken during that 28 day block.

I'm sure there is some awesome way to do this with a list comprehension, but the best I can come up with is to use a few `for` loops to generate a list, then use that list in the DataFrame.

I would love to have someone point me toward a less clunky way to accomplish this. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
num_vaca = []

for idx, month_start in enumerate(df.index):
    counter = 0
    for day in vaca_days:
        if day >= month_start and day <= df.index[idx + 1]:
            counter += 1
    num_vaca.append(counter)

df['Vacation Days'] = num_vaca
```

This seems to work *okay*, I'm just sure there's a better way.

EDIT: I haven't explained the problem very well, and I think some examples might help.

```
vaca_days = [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 6, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 7, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 0, 0)]

dr = pd.date_range('11/1/2012', periods = 6, freq = 'M')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dr)), index = dr, columns = ['Random'])
df

# Output:
              Random
2012-11-30 -0.134878
2012-12-31  0.066865
2013-01-31  0.630906
2013-02-28 -0.512881
2013-03-31  0.361890
2013-04-30 -1.019923


# Code from above
num_vaca = []

for idx, month_start in enumerate(df.index):
    counter = 0
    for day in vaca_days:
        if day >= month_start and day <= df.index[idx + 1]:
            counter += 1
    num_vaca.append(counter)

df['Vacation Days'] = num_vaca

df
# Output
              Random  Vacation Days
2012-11-30 -0.134878              0
2012-12-31  0.066865              6
2013-01-31  0.630906              3
2013-02-28 -0.512881              0
2013-03-31  0.361890              0
2013-04-30 -1.019923              0
```

Still having some issues with dealing with the last index value and the `[idx + 1]`, since I haven't defined where that time period should stop.

---

Update Feb 10, 2014

I was able to get @Andy-Hayden's response to work, with a little elbow grease. Here are the the issues I ran into, and the best workaround I could figure out.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# Generate a DataFrame with some random data and 28d date periods
dr = pd.date_range('11/6/2012', periods = 12, freq = 'W-Tue')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(dr)), index = dr, columns = ['column1'])
df = df.resample(rule = '28D', how = 'mean')

# The start dates for each period
df
#              column1
# 2012-11-06 -0.134757
# 2012-12-04 -0.382133
# 2013-01-01 -0.468343
# 2013-01-29  0.000000
# [4 rows x 1 columns]

# Vacation dates
vaca_days = list(pd.date_range(start = '2012-12-1', periods = 12, freq = 'D'))
vaca_days
# Timestamp('2012-12-01 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-02 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-03 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-04 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-05 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-06 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-07 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-08 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-09 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-10 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-11 00:00:00', tz=None),
#  Timestamp('2012-12-12 00:00:00', tz=None)]

# Clearly there should be 3 vacation dates in the 2012-11-06 period
# and 9 vacation dates in the 2013-12-04 period
# ---------------------------
# This gives me wrong numbers, because it tries to start the period on vaca_days[0]
pd.Series(1, vaca_days).resample('28D', how='sum')
# 2012-12-01    12
# 2012-12-29     0
# Freq: 28D, dtype: int64

# No help here
pd.Series(1, vaca_days).resample('28D', how='sum').shift(-1)
# 2012-12-01     0
# 2012-12-29   NaN
# Freq: 28D, dtype: float64

# The only workaround I could figure out: Append on the first start day
vaca_days.append(pd.Timestamp('2012-11-06'))

vaca_series = pd.Series([0] + [1 for each in vaca_days[:-1]], sorted(vaca_days))
vaca_series = vaca_series.resample(rule = '28D', how = sum)

vaca_series
# 2012-11-06    3
# 2012-12-04    9
# 2013-01-01    0
# Freq: 28D, dtype: int64

df['Vacation Days'] = vaca_series
df['Vacation Days'] = df['Vacation Days'].fillna(0)
df

#                   column1  Vacation Days
# 2012-11-06  -4.761727e-01              3
# 2012-12-04   5.715697e-01              9
# 2013-01-01   4.065451e-02              0
# 2013-01-29  2.781364e-309              0
# [4 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) by month using sum as the aggregation function:

```
In [11]: pd.Series(1, vaca_days).resample('M', how='sum')
Out[11]: 
2013-01-31    6
2013-02-28    3
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

When you set this as the column, it'll align the index for you:

```
In [12]: df['vac_days'] = pd.Series(1, vaca_days).resample('M', how='sum')

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
              Random  vac_days
2012-11-30 -0.134878       NaN
2012-12-31  0.066865       NaN
2013-01-31  0.630906         6
2013-02-28 -0.512881         3
2013-03-31  0.361890       NaN
2013-04-30 -1.019923       NaN

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now you definitely want to [fill in the NaN](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with 0. Given your desired solution it looks like you want to [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) the results up by one too...

```
In [14]: df['vac_days'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
Out[14]: 
2012-11-30    0
2012-12-31    6
2013-01-31    3
2013-02-28    0
2013-03-31    0
2013-04-30    0
Name: vac_days, dtype: float64

In [15]: df['vac_days'] = df['vac_days'].shift(-1).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had this idea as well; the problem I ran into was unconventional start dates. Your example works smoothly because both `pd.date_range` and `.resample` result in a `DatetimeIndex` starting on the same day. However, my time periods were 28 day blocks (Tuesday to Monday). I couldn't find a way to get `.resample` to work properly with this index, it always started near `vaca_days[0]` even when this didn't align with my index. No help from `.shift()` or `loffset`. My eventual workaround was to add an extra blank day to `vaca_days[0]` at the proper start date.